org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The node does not support GET_TELEMETRY_SUBSCRIPTIONS
I am developing Kafka Stream example in java and getting below error when I start the app.
Error:
17:34:38.930 [kafka-admin-client-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-admin] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [AdminClient clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-admin] Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-admin, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=1, host='localhost', port=9092, rack=null)], clusterId='MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qg', controllerId=1, topics=[], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
17:34:38.924 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] Version mismatch when attempting to send GetTelemetrySubscriptionsRequestData(clientInstanceId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) with correlation id 3 to -1
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The node does not support GET_TELEMETRY_SUBSCRIPTIONS
17:34:38.931 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams -- stream-client [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf] Started 1 stream threads
17:34:38.931 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter -- The broker generated an error for the get telemetry network API request
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The node does not support GET_TELEMETRY_SUBSCRIPTIONS
17:34:38.931 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter -- Updating intervalMs: 300000, lastRequestMs: 1713614678931
17:34:38.932 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter -- Setting telemetry state from SUBSCRIPTION_IN_PROGRESS to SUBSCRIPTION_NEEDED
17:34:38.931 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread -- stream-thread [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] Starting
17:34:38.934 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread -- stream-thread [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] State transition from CREATED to STARTING
17:34:38.936 [kafka-admin-client-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-admin] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager -- [AdminClient clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-admin] Updating cluster metadata to Cluster(id = MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qg, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], partitions = [], controller = localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null))
17:34:38.933 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=1, host='localhost', port=9092, rack=null)], clusterId='MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qg', controllerId=1, topics=[], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
17:34:38.940 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Subscribed to topic(s): words
17:34:38.940 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] Cluster ID: MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qg
17:34:38.940 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 2 to MetadataCache{clusterId='MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qg', nodes={1=localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)}, partitions=[], controller=localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)}
17:34:38.941 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] Received INIT_PRODUCER_ID response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=INIT_PRODUCER_ID, apiVersion=4, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer, correlationId=2, headerVersion=2): InitProducerIdResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, producerId=26, producerEpoch=0)
17:34:38.941 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread -- stream-thread [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] Invoking poll on main Consumer
17:34:38.941 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] ProducerId set to 26 with epoch 0
17:34:38.941 [kafka-producer-network-thread | my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager -- [Producer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-producer] Transition from state INITIALIZING to READY
17:34:38.942 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Sending FindCoordinator request to broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
17:34:38.944 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils -- Resolved host localhost as 127.0.0.1
17:34:38.944 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Resolved host localhost to addresses [localhost/127.0.0.1]
17:34:38.945 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
17:34:38.950 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 342972, SO_SNDBUF = 146988, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
17:34:38.951 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
17:34:38.951 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
17:34:38.951 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.7.0')
17:34:38.957 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Received API_VERSIONS response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2): ApiVersionsResponseData(errorCode=0, apiKeys=[ApiVersion(apiKey=0, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=1, minVersion=0, maxVersion=15), ApiVersion(apiKey=2, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=3, minVersion=0, maxVersion=12), ApiVersion(apiKey=8, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=9, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=10, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=11, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=12, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=13, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=14, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=15, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=16, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=17, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=18, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=19, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=20, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=21, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=22, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=23, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=24, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=25, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=26, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=27, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=28, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=29, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=30, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=31, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=32, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=33, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=34, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=35, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=36, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=37, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=38, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=39, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=40, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=41, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=42, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=43, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=44, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=45, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=46, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=47, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=48, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=49, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=50, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=51, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=55, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=57, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=60, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=61, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=64, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=65, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=66, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0)], throttleTimeMs=0, supportedFeatures=[SupportedFeatureKey(name='metadata.version', minVersion=1, maxVersion=14)], finalizedFeaturesEpoch=5580, finalizedFeatures=[FinalizedFeatureKey(name='metadata.version', maxVersionLevel=14, minVersionLevel=14)], zkMigrationReady=false)
17:34:38.961 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Node -1 has finalized features epoch: 5580, finalized features: [FinalizedFeatureKey(name='metadata.version', maxVersionLevel=14, minVersionLevel=14)], supported features: [SupportedFeatureKey(name='metadata.version', minVersion=1, maxVersion=14)], ZK migration ready: false, API versions: (Produce(0): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Fetch(1): 0 to 15 [usable: 15], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], Metadata(3): 0 to 12 [usable: 12], LeaderAndIsr(4): UNSUPPORTED, StopReplica(5): UNSUPPORTED, UpdateMetadata(6): UNSUPPORTED, ControlledShutdown(7): UNSUPPORTED, OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListGroups(16): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], EndTxn(26): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ElectLeaders(43): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartitionReassignments(45): 0 [usable: 0], ListPartitionReassignments(46): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetDelete(47): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeClientQuotas(48): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterClientQuotas(49): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeUserScramCredentials(50): 0 [usable: 0], AlterUserScramCredentials(51): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeQuorum(55): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartition(56): UNSUPPORTED, UpdateFeatures(57): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], Envelope(58): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeCluster(60): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], UnregisterBroker(64): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeTransactions(65): 0 [usable: 0], ListTransactions(66): 0 [usable: 0], AllocateProducerIds(67): UNSUPPORTED, ConsumerGroupHeartbeat(68): UNSUPPORTED, ConsumerGroupDescribe(69): UNSUPPORTED, GetTelemetrySubscriptions(71): UNSUPPORTED, PushTelemetry(72): UNSUPPORTED, ListClientMetricsResources(74): UNSUPPORTED).
17:34:38.961 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Sending metadata request MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='words')], allowAutoTopicCreation=false, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
17:34:38.961 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=2, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='words')], allowAutoTopicCreation=false, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
17:34:38.962 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Give up sending telemetry request since no node is available
17:34:38.962 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Sending FIND_COORDINATOR request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=4, clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=0, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: FindCoordinatorRequestData(key='', keyType=0, coordinatorKeys=[my-ktable-demo])
17:34:38.963 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Give up sending telemetry request since no node is available
17:34:38.963 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter -- Creating telemetry subscription request with client instance id AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
17:34:38.963 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter -- Setting telemetry state from SUBSCRIPTION_NEEDED to SUBSCRIPTION_IN_PROGRESS
17:34:38.963 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -- [Consumer clientId=my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-ktable-demo] Version mismatch when attempting to send GetTelemetrySubscriptionsRequestData(clientInstanceId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) with correlation id 3 to -1
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The node does not support GET_TELEMETRY_SUBSCRIPTIONS
17:34:38.963 [my-ktable-demo-881a7b7e-9830-4e3c-b7b8-eeaf70a26bbf-StreamThread-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.telemetry.internals.ClientTelemetryReporter -- The broker generated an error for the get telemetry network API request
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The node does not support GET_TELEMETRY_SUBSCRIPTIONS

I've no clue what's creating problem.
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>09-ktable-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

KTableDemo.java
@Slf4j
public class KTableDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-ktable-demo"); // consumer group
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");

        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KTable<String, String> wordsTable = streamsBuilder
                .table(WORDS, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()), Materialized.as("words-store"));

        wordsTable.filter((key, value) -> value.length() > 2)
                .toStream()
                .print(Printed.<String, String>toSysOut().withLabel("words-table"));

        KafkaStreams myStream = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), props);
        myStream.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Stopping Stream");
            myStream.close();
        }));
    }
}


This is a new feature of Kafka 3.7.0... Are you running that? If not, you'll want to downgrade your kafka streams dependency, probably https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15601

even with the lower version my app still complaning unable to connect. Do you know how to start confluent kafka locally with Java 17?

I use Docker. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/platform-quickstart.html#quickstart

Would you mind sharing docker-compose.yaml pls?

There's one linked in that post. And you seem to already have one. But do you not have any broker running? How were you testing your Spring XML questions?

In any case, Confluent Platform doesn't run Kafka 3.7.0, so that's why you might see errors about telemetry, or the real error says no node is available

Ah ok - I am clear on telemetry error, as you pointed out I am using the same docker-cpmpose from my project, even after I lower down the version of kafka-stream I am getting other errors which is very weird

Feel free to [edit] your question to include the other errors
